# Are there practical applications for a method of finding n! using the constant resulting in the differences between exponents of consecutive numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial, computational-mathematics

I have been tinkering with a variation of Pascal's triangle using the differences between the exponents of consecutive numbers to derive a factorial.

Generally, the bottom row starts with 1^n , 2^n , 3^n ... (n+1)^n , (n+2)^n
(the bottom row contains n + 2 digits)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCM3j.jpg)

For example, to calculate 3! (n=3), you start with :
1^3, 2^3, 3^3, 4^3, 5^3

5^3-4^3 = 61, 4^3-3^3 = 37, 3^3-2^3 = 19, 2^3-1^3 = 7

61-37 = 24, 37-19 = 18, 19-7 = 12

24-18 = 6, 18-12 = 6

So the constant is 6, which is 3!

I've tried this with larger numbers and the constant so far has been n!

If this is confusing, I have attempted to attach a page with the hand-written calculations.

Thank you kindly for any constructive help!

Comment: this is correct. The traditional phrase for the methods was the Calculus of Finite Differences. A modern treatment is Conway and Guy, The Book of Numbers....My father called the whole business "successive differences"  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Toshio-Fukushima/publication/318310493_Jordan%27s_Calculus_of_Finite_Differences_2nd_edn_Jordan_1950/data/596236bfaca2728c11033d01/CalculusofFiniteDifferences.pdf

Comment: That's a lot of operations to get $3!$. It's not a very efficient method. To calculate $n!$, one can use numbers whose sums add up to an even or odd sum of squares. See here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/what-are-the-benefits-of-cutting-by-half-the-number-of-multiplications-needed-to

Comment: There is also this method that uses difference of squares to calculate factorials. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711223/does-using-pre-computed-squares-speed-up-significantly-the-calculation-of-factor